# Is this a stochastic integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-integrals

So I'm reading this paper about modeling the spread of a disease and the paper describes pretty much every other variable that they're using in this particular equation (that gives us the $\lambda_i$ for an exponential distribution used for a stochastic model), except for the last integral which I'm not sure I completely understand. I've taken a class in which we worked with some stochastic calculus, though not in detail, so it looks moderately like a stochastic integral to me, but I'm not exactly sure. Can someone confirm this?

The equation is this:
$$\lambda_i(t) = C(t)\bigg(1-\frac{N(t)}{N_{pop}}\bigg)R_iF(t-T_{I,i} - T_{iso,i })
\int^{t+\delta t}_{t} W(\tau-T_{I,i})d\tau$$

where $\lambda_i(t)$ is the mean for a Poisson distribution at each time step, $C(t)$ is the transmission rate of the disease, $1-\frac{N(t)}{N_{pop}}$ is the amount of the population that is at risk for the disease at time $t$, $T_{iso}$ is the time taken to isolate after infection, and $T_I$ is the time at which some individual gets infected. Lastly, $F(t)$ is a function that describes the reduction of transmission of the disease, described by another function that I am not mentioning here because it does not add much to the question I'm asking.

The only thing not mentioned or described is the integral at the end, and I *thinkkk* that it's a stochastic/ito integral, but I'm not completely sure. If it was though, how would I calculate an answer for this for example, taking a specific time step, and working for that? I know it's different from regular integration, however, I can't seem to understand how to get an answer for this.

Could anyone help explain?

Thank you!!

Comment: The most important information is missing: what is $W$?  But on its face this looks like a plain ordinary Riemann integral of a function that happens to be random.  The tipoff is $d\tau$ which looks like the differential of time: a stochastic integral would have $dW_\tau$ or something similar, the differential of the process.

Comment: Yess, that's what I was having a problem with. The $W$ isn't mentioned anywhere in the paper, and is just used in the integral as far as I know. The reason why I thought it might have been a stochastic integral is because it was used in a paper using a stochastic model specifically. Does the $W_t$ have to be there though? Also I see, that's interesting. So in this case, this could just be a regular integral? If I wanted to solve for a particular $\lambda_i(t)$ by using particular values for each other variable there, how would I solve the integral?

Comment: In the part where I asked if the $W_t$ has to be there, I mean, does the t (tau in your comment) part *have* to be there for it to be a stochastic integral?

Comment: There can be some variation in the notation between authors.  Some might write $dW(t)$ instead, or omit it if it doesn't need to match a $t$ in the integrand.  Basically it's supposed to be analogous to a line integral, except that you're integrating along a curve which is non-differentiable so the classical definition of the line integral doesn't work.  But the notation would usually be generally similar to the notation for a line integral.

Comment: Note that, even for an ordinary time integral, when the function you're integrating is random (i.e. depends on the outcome $\omega$ as well as on time), then the result will be a random variable as well.  So you can't "solve" the integral in the sense of obtaining a single number as the result.  When you have a linear function of the Brownian motion, as in this case, the resulting random variable will have a Gaussian distribution, whose mean and variance can be found with Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Ahhhh I see I see, that's interesting. If its not too much trouble, could you suggest a book/web page where I can read more about this? (Also if you would happen to know where I can read more about continuous time branching models, could you please suggest something for that as well? I'm trying to understand the paper that I'm reading better, but I can't find any information that I'm actually able to comprehend)